# PHP - Scraping data of website using HTML DOM

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the specific data from a website but couldn't make any progress.. I have found a solution of parsing html dom.. it is working fine for other websites but not for the one which i want to scrape. showing this error

> Warning:
> file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/):
> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 No such file
> in route folder / simple_html_dom.php on line 641
>
> AdvancedHtmlDom Object ( [xpath] => [root] => [doc] => AdvancedHtmlDom
> Object *RECURSION* [dom] => [node] => [is_text] => )

I want to scrape this data using simple_html_dom not using Curl .. If anyone have the idea how to fix this issue .

**index.php**

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');

print_r($html);



?>
```

**Code on line 641**

```
function str_get_html($html)
    { 
       return new AdvancedHtmlDom($html);
     }

function file_get_html($url)
  { 
         return str_get_html(file_get_contents($url)); 
  }
```

Comment: You should read this : http://www.betexplorer.com/terms-of-service.php

Comment: Without you showing us the content of `simple_html_dom.php` we can't help you, since the error must be in there.

Comment: I've edited my code.. since i don't want to bother you reading 600 lines of codes.. i have just pasted the function written on line 641.. which is causing error..